# What is the correct name for a "product function" on a monoid?

Tags: functions, noncommutative-algebra, semigroups, monoid, free-product

Let $W$ be a monoid. A function $f\colon W\rightarrow W$ is a "product function" if $f(w)$ is a product of constants in $W$ and positive integer powers of $w$. It could also be called a "non-commutative arithmetic sequence". I'd like to use the correct name to refer to these functions as well as the related monoid of "formal product functions in an unknown variable", isomorphic to $W * \langle x \rangle$, the free product of W and the free monoid in a single generator, $\langle x\rangle = \{1,x,x^2,x^3,\ldots\}$. These have the same relation as polynomial functions in a ring $R$ to formal polynomials with coefficients in $R$.

Comment: In Universal algebra they are also called polynomials, or polynomial term functions.  ( I'm assuming one uses the same polynomial for each input w to f and not different polynomials for different w for the same f.) Gerhard "Don't Know About Category Theory" Paseman, 2020.05.22.

Comment: I think semigroup theorists would also say polynomial though monomial would be more accurate

Comment: @GerhardPaseman What articles / books use these terms? I can only find references to polynomials in the context of ring theory.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg What articles / books use these terms? I can only find references to polynomials in the context of ring theory.

Comment: The universal algebra texts I used have this terminology. McKenzie McNulty Taylor wrote one, Burris Sankappanavar another. There is a book about polynomial algebras one of whose authors I think is Reinhold Poeschel.  The terminology may be standard in the field since 1980, and before then universal algebra texts were less plentiful and terminological issues abounded.  Gerhard "The Language, She Is A-Changin'" Paseman, 2020.05.22.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman Thanks, I'll take a look. However, my interests are not in the direction of universal algebra. Have you seen or heard such a function called a "geometric progression"?

Comment: No, and unless you are dealing with commutative monoids, I would not use it here.  You might look at the literature on combinatorics on words to see bow such functions might be used.  Gerhard "Progression Often Means Constant Change" Paseman, 2020.05.22.

Comment: I don't know a reference off the top of my head but it is what all semigroup theorists use at talks and also all universal algebraists.

Comment: It's used in an answer here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/153883/relatively-free-groups-in-vars-3 for groups  but without allowing constants

Comment: Polynomials are used here https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/42938384.pdf for groups but the authors are semigroup theorists.

Comment: However the classical paper on this stuff from the semigroup point of view https://www-ams-org.ccny-proxy1.libr.ccny.cuny.edu/journals/proc/1965-016-03/S0002-9939-1965-0175971-0/home.html users the word product function from your title.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg I think you need to set up a proxy to see https://www-ams-org.ccny-proxy1.libr.ccny.cuny.edu/journals/proc/1965-016-03/S0002-9939-1965-0175971-0/home.html because it sends me to a generic page after redirecting.

Comment: Here is another link for the same paper: https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1965-016-03/S0002-9939-1965-0175971-0/S0002-9939-1965-0175971-0.pdf

Comment: Sorry. The paper is A Property of Finite Simple Non-Abelian Groups

W. D. Maurer and John L. Rhodes
Proceedings of the American Mathematical Society
Vol. 16, No. 3 (Jun., 1965), pp. 552-554

Comment: This has been cross-posted to MathOverflow: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/361107/what-is-the-correct-name-for-a-product-function-on-a-monoid